# navigation bar under status bar after video playback in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

The problem:

Navigation bar is under status bar after playing video in landscape mode.

The application:

- iOS9 only.
- only supports portrait mode.
- the view controller have a web view on it, web view will open a youtube link
- the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller

Setups to reproduce:

1. Play a video in a webView,
2. Put device into landscape mode.
3. Dismiss video play in landscape mode, app goes back to portrait mode
4. Navigation bar is in wrong position

Screenshots:

1. When app opens

[image: when app opens]

2. Play video and put the device in landscape

[image]

3. The problem:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Swift 3**

In the presenting view controller, override the `prefersStatusBarHidden` property to only hide the status bar if it's in landscape.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
}
```

Then add an observer for when the device is rotated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoDidRotate), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}
```

In the observer's method, call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`:

```
func videoDidRotate() {
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Converted it to Objective-C and it works like a charm. Thank you .

Comment: I was experiencing exactly the same issue on iOS10 and iOS11, and I've spent a whole day trying to fix it, until I found this solution. Thank you very much for this answer.

Comment: Working almost perfect, but... when you tap "done" in the video, while still holding the device in landscape orientation, it won't show status bar until you'll rotate your device back into portrait.

Answer (score 11):

It's very simple,

**swift 3**

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();
   UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only one worked for me.

Comment: UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden is deprecated

Answer (score 8):

@Aaron answer almost works, there's only one problem: when you tap "done" in the video, while still holding the device in landscape orientation, it won't show status bar until you'll rotate your device back into portrait.

In that case, I've added notification observer when "done" button is tapped and then I switch to portrait programmatically.

My code is in Objective C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoDidRotate) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closedFullScreen:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)closedFullScreen:(NSNotification *)myNotification{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                    forKey:@"orientation"];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
}

- (void)videoDidRotate {
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

EDIT:

View controller-based status bar appearance in .plist file must be set to YES.

Comment: just for clarification is this on the root controller or the controller that contains the YouTube view?

Comment: controller that contains the YouTube view

Comment: Strange, it does not seem to work for me. my heighrarchy looks like this: controller -> container -> navigation controller -> controller -> YoutubeView. probably too complex but its a bit too far to change atm

Comment: View controller-based status bar appearance in .plist file must be set to YES.

Comment: This was the answer for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Makalele's answer but didn't not quite working (or it might but got blocked due to other test code).  After some test and try, I end up with something simpler than that.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)
                   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                 object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)
                   name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                 object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}


- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
}
```

A few things to notice

1. You can call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` directly using selector.
2. Added a `removeObserver` call when view disappears.
3. The return value of `prefersStatusBarHidden` must be changed from time-to-time.

So, in the view controller that contains the YouTube view, you will see the status bar disappears before entering YouTube fullscreen.  It will returns when the YouTube playing is completed (via `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` event).

Just in case that this event doesn't trigger, the other event: `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, will still trigger whenever user rotates the screen (even the orientation is locked).

So, @Makalele's solution has double route to trigger status bar.

I found that I don't need `UIDevice:setValue:forKey:` but your mileage may vary.

Credit to @Makalele and @Aaron.